# Explode method is not exploding the string in php

Tags: php, html-table, explode

This is the code, but `explode()` method is not splitting the data from string at `<tr>` occurrence. Let me know what I am doing wrong in this simple case. Better if not to use regex  in this case.

**EDIT**

It is working in Codepad codepad.org/K9ETKzUN but browser is not outputting the php rendered code.

```
<?php

$tabledata = '<table width="90%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" border="3" bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
<tbody>

<tr>
<th>No</th>
<th>AnimalNo</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th colspan="1">Sub1</th>
<th colspan="1">Sub2</th>
<th colspan="1">Sub3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th colspan="1"></th>
<th colspan="1"></th>
<th colspan="1"></th>
<th colspan="1">Subpart1</th>
<th colspan="1">Subpart2</th>
<th colspan="1">Subpart3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th colspan="1"></th>
<th colspan="1"></th>
<th colspan="1"></th>
<td class="countcompfield">Max mark1</td>
<td class="countcompfield">Max mark2</td>
<td class="countcompfield">Max mark3</td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td></td>
<td>A1</td>
<td>Name1</td>
<td>34</td>
<td>56</td>
<td>67</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td>B2</td>
<td>Name2</td>
<td>89</td>
<td>76</td>
<td>56</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td>C1</td>
<td>Name3</td>
<td>34</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>23</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>';

$myarr = explode('<tr>',$tabledata);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myarr);
```

Comment: What is the output you *are* getting?

Comment: Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php to manipulate HTML. Forget about explode or regex.

Comment: I just tested this code and it works. Notice that `explode()` will remove the `<tr>` from the result.

Comment: @L0j1k getting an array and whole table at the last index value rest all blank

Comment: what is the point of this anyway?

Comment: What are you getting as response.

Comment: It works as expected, check html source in external source viewer, don't use inspect element

Comment: Just for S&Gs, try setting a limit temporarily: `$myarr = explode('<tr',$tabledata,10);` and see what happens.

Comment: @MarkoD Its is working in Codepad http://codepad.org/K9ETKzUN but running in browser it wont

Comment: It's working in browser too, but it's not displaying it correctly, that's why I told you to check source in external source viewer

Comment: PHP doesn't run in the browser.

Comment: @MarkoD Yes I checked and its thr...thanks a lot

Comment: @melpomene I am sure we all know that :)

Comment: @MarkoD I'm sure user1594368 doesn't.

Comment: @melpomene i am sure out of many things you too dont know all as well..the point is to tell someone about the mistake not blaming some one for which he/she is unaware off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working...
Run the script and see source.

Right click -> view source

Answer (score 1):

The code posted works. The problem you have is that you are viewing the result in a browser as a web page, and that causes all but the last element to remain hidden. If you view>source in your browser, you'll see the expected and correct result.

A better option for HTML parsing is the native [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

> Its working in Codepad codepad.org/K9ETKzUN but running in browser it wont

That's because Codepad doesn't replicate a browser, the output on Codepad is literal text. HTML tags are not interpreted as they are on a web page.

Comment: Yes you are very correct I just checked in and its thr ..+1

Answer (score 1):

How you concluded it's not exploding? perhaps by looking at the output of the print_r in browser, you are getting it wrong actually. Whatever you have done is working correctly. Replace print_r($myarr) with var_dump($myarr) and you will see what I mean.

Browser is just rendering the table together in the end :)